# React JS Sorting and Stacking list value

Tags: javascript, sorting, bubble-sort

Assume

```
const listA = [{"key":"apple", "value":100}, {"key":"banana", "value":50}, {"key":"pearl", "value":10}, {"key":"cherry", "value":5}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":3}]
const listB = [{"key":"peach", "value":30}, {"key":"apple", "value":15}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":10}, {"key":"mango", "value":5}]
```

As you can see, in the array it got each object pair with "key " and "value", I wish to stack up the value for the same key in new build list, the new build list also needs to be in desc order by value , e.g something like this  ->

```
const listMerged = [{"key":"apple", "value":115}, {"key":"banana", "value":50} , {"key":"peach", "value":30}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":13}, {"key":"pearl", "value":10}, {"key":"cherry", "value":5}, {"key":"mango", "value":5}]
```

Just tried something like this ->

```
let newArr = listB.forEach((item) => {

  let ifElemPresentInListA = listA.findIndex((elem) => {
    return Object.keys(elem)[0] === Object.keys(item)[0]
  })

  if (ifElemPresentInListA === -1) {
    listA.push(item)
  } else {
    for (let keys in listA[ifElemPresentInListA]) {
      listA[ifElemPresentInListA][keys] += Object.values(item)[0]
    }
  }

})
```

But result is a bit messed up

Would be really appricate if anyone could suggest better code example. Thanks

Comment: Just so you know, this is a javascript question independent of react (you might get more answers labeling it as such)

Comment: Most of the community encourages you to post some sort of code of possible solutions you may have tried.

Comment: A side note: `Array.forEach` does not return anything, newArr will be `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip two arrays into object to sum values for matching keys and then create array from object back:

```js
const listA = [{"key":"apple", "value":100}, {"key":"banana", "value":50}, {"key":"pearl", "value":10}, {"key":"cherry", "value":5}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":3}];
const listB = [{"key":"peach", "value":30}, {"key":"apple", "value":15}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":10}, {"key":"mango", "value":5}];

let result = [...listA, ...listB].reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.key] = acc[item.key] ? acc[item.key] + item.value : item.value
  return acc;
}, {});

result = Object.entries(result)
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ key, value }))
  .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a potential solution that concatenates the list, sorts by keys, and then iterates through the concatenated/sorted array to conditionally add or increment in a new list.

```js
const listA = [{"key":"apple", "value":100}, {"key":"banana", "value":50}, {"key":"pearl", "value":10}, {"key":"cherry", "value":5}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":3}]
const listB = [{"key":"peach", "value":30}, {"key":"apple", "value":15}, {"key":"kiwi", "value":10}, {"key":"mango", "value":5}]

let lists = [];

listA.concat(listB).sort((a, b) => a.key > b.key).forEach(el => {
  if (lists.length > 0 && lists[lists.length - 1].key === el.key) {
    lists[lists.length - 1].value += el.value;
  } else {
    lists.push(el);
  }
});

console.log(lists.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value));
```

Comment: when run code snippet, the result of values do not increment.

Comment: I think the desire was to see the result in reverse order by value (i.e., highest to lowest value)

Answer (score 2):

You could take a Map and collect all key/value pairs and then sort the new array.

```js
const
    listA = [{ key: "apple", value: 100 }, { key: "banana", value: 50 }, { key: "pearl", value: 10 }, { key: "cherry", value: 5 }, { key: "kiwi", value: 3 }],
    listB = [{ key: "peach", value: 30 }, { key: "apple", value: 15 }, { key: "kiwi", value: 10 }, { key: "mango", value: 5 }],
    result = Array
        .from(
            [...listA, ...listB].reduce((m, { key, value }) => m.set(key, (m.get(key) || 0) + value), new Map),
            ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
        )
        .sort(({ key: a }, { key: b }) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```